# Dialogflow & Express -- Fulfilment

Tags: typescript, express, google-api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm having an issue getting responses from dialogflow, when other express calls are working fine.

I know it's an issue with the agents, but I'm unsure what that issue is or how to fix it, which is why I'm asking on here.

Key points to note.

- This code is being added to a existing tested express application
- Been testing using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com)
- Dialogflow fullfillment template webhook can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how#webhook_request)
- console successfully outputs `We got hours!` then doesn't continue
- if you comment line `57 through 62 (the if section)` and uncomment line `56` code responds as expected
- Issue expected to be within the `agents.hours` function
- Have tried `this.currentlyOpen() === true` as well

Sooo many thanks in advance.

*dialogflow.ts*

```
// import { google } from 'googleapis';
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
// import { Card, Suggestion } from 'dialogflow-fulfillment';
/**
 * @private
 * Initialise the ai assist api
 */
export class Agents {
  aiassist:any

  async initialize (message:any) {
    var aiassist = {
      info: {
        configsuccess: false,
        message: message,
        data: [],
      }
    }
    process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';
    const url = message.headers.configlocation;
    await message.core.request({url: url, json: true}, function (error: any, response: { statusCode: number; }, data: any) {
      aiassist.info.data = data
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        aiassist.info.configsuccess = true
      }
      return aiassist
    })
    this.aiassist = aiassist
    this.WebhookProcessing();
  }

  /**
  * @private
  * Find the map the agent
  */
  WebhookProcessing () {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({request: this.aiassist.info.message.full, response: this.aiassist.info.message.res});

    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Hours', this.hours);

    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
  }

  /****************
  * AGENT        *
  *  DECLARATION *
  ****************/
  /**
  * [hours description]
  * @param  agent [description]
  * @return       [description]
  */
  hours (agent:any) {
    console.log("We got hours!")
    // agent.add(`We're open now! We close at 17:00 today. Is there anything else I can help you with?`);
    if (currentlyOpen(this.aiassist)) { // TypeError: Cannot read property 'aiassist' of undefined
      console.log("open!")
      agent.add(`We're open now! We close at 17:00 today. Is there anything else I can help you with?`);
    } else {
      console.log("closed!")
    }
  }

}

/******************
* FUNCTIONS      *
*    DECLARATION *
******************/

//  Check if currently open - Issues getting "aiassist" into this function
function currentlyOpen (aiassist:any) {
  // Get current datetime with proper timezone
  console.log("We got currentlyOpen!")
  // const date = new Date()
  console.log(aiassist.info.data.timeZoneOffset)
  // console.log("We finished currentlyOpen")
  // date.setHours(date.getHours() + parseInt(agent.this.aiassist.info.data.timeZoneOffset.split(':')[0]));
  // date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + parseInt(agent.this.aiassist.info.data.timeZoneOffset.split(':')[0][0] + agent.this.aiassist.info.data.timeZoneOffset.split(':')[1]));
  // return date.getDay() >= 1 &&
  // date.getDay() <= 5 &&
  // date.getHours() >= agent.this.aiassist.info.data.businessSetings.openTime &&
  // date.getHours() <= agent.this.aiassist.info.data.businessSetings.closeTime;
  return true
}
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'aiassist' of undefined
  File "C:\Users\sjona\Desktop\TSC\repo\curr\built\routes\v1\dialogflow.js", line 53, col 32, in hours
    if (currentlyOpen(this.aiassist)) {
  File "C:\Users\sjona\Desktop\TSC\repo\curr\node_modules\dialogflow-fulfillment\src\dialogflow-fulfillment.js", line 313, col 44, in WebhookClient.handleRequest
    let result = handler.get(this.intent)(this);
  File "C:\Users\sjona\Desktop\TSC\repo\curr\built\routes\v1\dialogflow.js", line 39, col 15, in Agents.WebhookProcessing
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
  File "C:\Users\sjona\Desktop\TSC\repo\curr\built\routes\v1\dialogflow.js", line 29, col 14, in Agents.initialize
    this.WebhookProcessing();
```

EDIT: 
Updated code to match comment. Added note where issues arise.

Comment: just moved `currentlyOpen` out of the class to fix part of the issue, it now calls the function. Still very unsure how to get the `aiassist` data into this function

Comment: We don't see line numbers, so it is a little difficult to understand what you're trying to say the issue is.

Comment: @Prisoner hopefully my edit helps. Sorry about that x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `this` isn't what you think it is (or want it to be) due to how `hours()` gets called and how `this` has different meanings depending how it is called. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) goes into the gory details, but in short (as it applies to you):

- A function that gets called has `this` applied to the *global object*, not to the lexically bound version of `this` (ie - the value of `this` inside a class
- To get the lexically bound version of `this`, you need to bind the value to the function using `bind()`, or use an arrow function to make the call.

In your case, this means that you should be registering the Intent Handler with something like

```
intentMap.set('Hours', agent => this.hours(agent));
```